# How to get distance from a circle in OL6

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

How to get distance from draw circle feature,?

```
const radius = feature.getGeometry().getRadius();
```

The radius can be obtained.
(Is this pixel?)

want a meter.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be in the units used by the projection you are displaying it in.  Typically that will be EPSG:3857 web mercator which uses meters as nominal units,  but that is a true scale only at the equator - at 60 degrees north things appear twice the true size, so you should adjust your result for point resolution, and also explicitly specify meters if your projection uses a different unit:

```
ol.proj.getPointResolution(map.getView().getProjection(), feature.getGeometry().getRadius(), feature.getGeometry().getCenter(), 'm')
```

Comment: The answer I was looking for.